# SFML C++ why is nothing drawn on screen here? (simple code)

Tags: c++, sfml

Here is my example program using SFML library in C++. I want to create a custom function 'draw_func' which draws something (like a rectangle in this example) at provided coordinates. I set the type of the return variable as an sfml object rectangle (which is what I return and what I draw) but the screen is black.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "SFML/OpenGL.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

sf::RectangleShape draw_func(int x, int y)
{
    sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(200, 100));
    rect.setPosition(x, y);
    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color((0, 0, 255)));
    return rect;
}


int main()
{

    int height = 400;
    int length = 400;
    int pos_x = 0;
    int pos_y = 0;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(length, height), "My window");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        sf::RectangleShape rectangle = draw_func(pos_x, pos_y);
        window.draw(rectangle);
        window.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you intend these extra parentheses `sf::Color((0, 0, 255))`?

Comment: Oh wow, I was changing that part from rect.setFillColor(0,0,255) to what is posted here and somehow managed to add extra. Thanks, everything works, I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is with this statemen here:

```
rect.setFillColor(sf::Color((0, 0, 255)));
```

The double parentheses actually resolves to a single value, `0` because:

```
sf::Color((0, 0, 255))
```

constructs a `sf::Color` with the value `0` because

```
(0, 0, 255)
```

is **not** function parameters because of the extra parentheses it is an *expression* involving the *comma operator*:

```
0, 0, 255
```

The *comma operator* always has the value of its *left most* expression. In this case `0`.

Now `sf::Color` has a constructor that takes a single value:

```
sf::Color(Uint32 color);
```

You are creating **black** `sf::Color(0)`.